# Framing a Wall with a Sloped Ceiling

Tags: walls, framing, slope

I'm building a new partition wall in a space where the existing ceiling is drywall attached to the sloped underside of studio-vault roof trusses. The new wall will be perpendicular to the trusses.

My question relates to the top plate: if I nail it directly to the trusses and angle-cut the tops of the studs, the faces of the top plate will not be flush with the faces of the studs, which will cause problems when installing the drywall.

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cut your top plate pieces into parallelograms that match the angle of the ceiling. If you are framing the wall with 2x4’s then you’ll need 2x6’s to cut from, or maybe even larger, depending on the angle. A steeper ceiling will require a wider parallelogram.

You can cut these top plate pieces easiest with a table saw or with more effort a hand rip saw.